# zend framework 2 random numbers and sessions

Tags: php, security, session, zend-framework2

I am working with zend framework 2, the problem I have is that I generate a random integer (saving it in a variable) and then store in the session (as a key in an array, in the value of the array I assign a value from the database), this is done in the GET method.
Then I return a form, which uses this random value.
I work with the form on the view entering some values, then the user makes a POST method to submit the form.
The issue I have is that the random value setted in the session changes its value when the POST is made but value corresponding to that key doesn´t change.

I do this to avoid a direct reference to an object.

I don´t understand why the value changes, is this related to security in zend?

Thanks for your help and sorry for my english,
Julio

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating the random integer in the same controller-action which also loads the form (the form which is filled and submitted via POST)?

If yes, then this is what happens -

1. The random integer is created.
2. This integer is stored in the session array as the "key".
3. The value from the database is set as the "value" for this "array-key".
4. The form loads, the form is filled and submitted.
5. Form's action attribute is same as the controller-action.
6. So after form submit, the code starts again with generating the random integer (new this time) but the value fetched from database is the same.

This is why only the random integer is changed but not the database value.

Now if the above scenario is not the case then,
 `please do check whether the random integer generation code is called after form submit or not. If yes then that's the reason for your new integer`.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I create the random integers in the same controller-action but I so somethin like:
`SomeAcion{
  If (isPost()){
     getSessionValue()
  } else {
     setSessionValue()
  }
}
`
I didn´t understand the second case.

Thanks for the reply!

Comment: I meant that whether the `setSessionValue()` is called again after submit or not. But never mind. It may be helpful if you could `print_r()` the session variable before submit and after submit. And  if possible include the array in the question.